# How to target .NET core 3 on visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I just install visual studio 2022. I can target **.NET 5.0** and **.NET 6.0**. Is it possible to add an older version, let's say **.NET core 3.0** because I'd like to watch a course that Scott Allen recorded on Pluralsight on razor pages.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, .NET 5 and .NET 6 are capable of everything .NET Core 3.0 can do, so you might find that leaving your project in .NET 6 is fine and that everything from your course works as you would expect.

If you really want to set the target framework to .NET Core 3.0, you can manually override the options presented in the Project Properties UI.

1. Open Solution Explorer
2. Find your project
3. Double-click it to open the project XML in the editor
4. Find the `<TargetFramework>` property and set its value to `netcoreapp3.0`